# @react-three/fiber node module not working in Expo app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, three.js, expo, react-three-fiber

I have an expo app .. all the mode modules are js ones. Now I am trying to add @react-three/fiber which I think is written in typescript. So, i feel the module is not working as expo is not compiling the ts or tsx files as it does with the js files. Can someone tell me how to make expo to build ts files also alongside the existing js files and node modules. Is expo capable of handling both js and ts in same project ? Below is the exception i am getting on opening the App

```
  * /<projectpath>/node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/native.js(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * /<projectpath>/node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/native.js/index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
Android Bundling failed 1083ms
While trying to resolve module `@react-three/fiber` from file `/<projectpath>/src/screens/spinner/spinner-3d-60deg.js`, the package `/<projectpath>/node_modules/@react-three/fiber/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/mnt/57b4f320-a355-468b-a1f5-2d4d156e25e8/projects/external/PickABoo/node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/native.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * /<projectpath>/node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/native.js(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * /<projectpath>/node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/native.js/index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure metro to compile typescript files.

Edit metro.config.js (located in your project's root folder) and make sure you have the following `sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx']` within your resolver options.

See relevant documentation here: https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration/#sourceexts

If you don't already have a metro.config.js file in your root folder, you can create one and enter the code below:

**metro.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx'], // this line compiles typescript
  },
};
```